# Up button is not worrking

Tags: android, up-button

I have implemented basic activity template in my project.But up button is not working in app, I have also modified menifest file. I am shring code sninipet for suggestion.

Edit: 
I am sharing the entire activity code in place of snippet

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

/**
 * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
 * to reflect its new value.
 */
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
            // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
            // using RingtoneManager.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

            } else {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                if (ringtone == null) {
                    // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                    preference.setSummary(null);
                } else {
                    // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                    // name.
                    String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                    preference.setSummary(name);
                }
            }

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

/**
 * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
 * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
 */

```
  private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= 
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
}


private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigationUp(){
 onBackPressed();
 return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    return isXLargeTablet(this);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
}
```

/**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
  */

```
 protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}

/**
 * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows data and sync preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Manifest File:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_order"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post settingsactivity xml

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Also write the method
@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

Comment: @Thirupathi  I have added the entire settings activity. Plz review and suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **set** the support action bar first.

Add this code to your xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

And than add this line to your Java code (**first line** in your set up function):

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar));
```

source: [developer.android.com: Setting Up The App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)